# Returning Level-1 Node In a Balanced Binary Search Tree Ruby?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am recursively creating a balanced binary search tree in Ruby using a sorted array. However, I'm having trouble at the ending return value. Instead of all the nodes bubbling up, creating a tree and returning the base level 1 node, the very last node at the bottom of the tree is returned.

It doesn't seem like the nodes being created are linked together at all (printing the instantiated class using `p list` only returns the last node). How do I link the nodes together and return the level 1 root node?

Code:

```
class Node
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right

  def initialize(value, left = nil, right = nil)
    @value = value
    @left = left
    @right = right
  end
end

class Tree
  attr_accessor :sorted_arr, :arr

  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
    @sorted_arr = arr.sort.uniq
  end

  #Problem: nodes not being linked together

  def build_tree(arr, start, last)
    if start > last
      return nil
    end

    mid_index = (start + last) / 2
    
    @root = Node.new(arr[mid_index])


    @root.left = build_tree(arr, start, mid_index - 1)
    @root.right = build_tree(arr, mid_index + 1, last)


    return @root
  end
end

list = Tree.new([1, 7, 4, 23, 8, 9, 4, 3, 6, 7, 9, 67, 6345, 324])
list.build_tree(list.sorted_arr, 0, list.sorted_arr.length-1)
p list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `root` instead of `@root`.
Those starting with `@` are instance variables, so when you're calling to:

```
@root.left = build_tree(arr, start, mid_index - 1)
```

inside of that `build_tree` call, eventually you'll call also to `@root = Node.new(arr[mid_index])` which it will replace the value already set in the parent call.